# Filter by datetime in Meilisearch

Tags: laravel, meilisearch

In the documentation: https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/filtering.html
Meilisearch compares dates like this:

```
title = Scream OR title = "The Avengers" AND release_date > 795484800
```

however the column I want to compare is using datetime, like so: `2021-05-31T19:52:08.000000Z`
How I can I filter a query using datetime? Like for example, only get the results that are less than a year old.

Comment: Hi! You'll need to transform them into timestamps, check this [issue](https://github.com/meilisearch/documentation/issues/840)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to transfer the date to a Unix timestamp.

In PHP, the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) tool can be used:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(2021-05-31T19:52:08.000000Z)->timestamp
```